# Wordpress OAuth1 with React Native

Tags: javascript, wordpress, react-native

I have deployed my wordpress site and am having trouble with the first step of OAuth Authentication that involves creating a signature (for now, I hardcoded the nonce and timestamp and copied and pasted the base string and the consumer secret into an online HMAC-SHA1 encoder (https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output) to create the signature.

Below is my code:

```js
const url = 'http://auth-test-site.azurewebsites.net/oauth1/request';
const base_string = 'POST&http%3A%2F%2Fauth-test-site.azurewebsites.net%2Foauth1%2Frequest&oauth_consumer_key%3DieQCM48wXWuW%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D123456789%26oauth_nonce%3Dnonce%26oauth_version%3D1.0';
        console.log(url);
        fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Authorization": "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=ieQCM48wXWuW,oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1,oauth_timestamp=123456789,oauth_nonce=FFeySWNH1Am,oauth_version=1.0,oauth_signature=5c6f358b1086cf2387e46a6c00e412fcfc2a4743",
            },
            credentials: "same-origin"
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.text());
            return response.text();
        }, function(error) {
            console.error(error.message) //=> String
        });
```

This is what is printed to the console:

```
06:44:31: http://auth-test-site.azurewebsites.net/oauth1/request
06:44:32: Promise {
06:44:32:   "_40": 0,
06:44:32:   "_55": "
06:44:32: Consumer Key is invalid",
06:44:32:   "_65": 1,
06:44:32:   "_72": null,
06:44:32: }
```

The consumer key is ieQCM48wXWuW and consumer secret is 9Yf0HG8RWrk0a4IKxwnkK2LUvd15NNF0b98jZwpOmQhoO7vv for the test user.
Does anyone have pointers to why the request isn't working? Thanks!

EDIT: I removed the triple-slashes and have made progress, but now I get this:

```
07:01:01: Promise {
07:01:01:   "_40": 0,
07:01:01:   "_55": "
07:01:01: OAuth signature does not match",
07:01:01:   "_65": 1,
07:01:01:   "_72": null,
07:01:01: }
```

Any ideas on how I can get a proper OAuth signature?

Comment: Is there a reason you're triple-slashing the quotes?

Comment: I had used postman earlier and it had given me this jquery code. Probably since the string itself is in quotes https://www.dropbox.com/s/1xy3f3bz3yv5pc9/post.PNG?dl=0